# How to install PHP on CentOS has preinstalled Apache HTTPD?

Tags: centos, php, apache-2.4, centos7, php7

I'm using CentOS 7. I wanted to install PHP 7 so I used `remi-php` (latest PHP version of `yum` is 5.4). Since the HTTPD version of `yum` is too old, I compiled the latest HTTPD version from the source code.

HTTPD compilation goes perfectly, however, when I try to install `remi-php` using the following command:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php71 install php php-cli php-intl php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mysqlnd
```

To install `php`, `yum` will also install the old version of `httpd` (although I have compiled and used the latest HTTPD version). If I continue with the installation, my HTTPD will throw an error (and won't start), but if I don't continue with the installation, I won't have the `php*.so` file and apache won't parse the `.php` files.

So, how do I install `php` without affecting the Apache HTTPD that I have compiled before? I don't want my server to have two instances of Apache HTTPD at the same time and may have problems in the future.

Your answer given will be very helpful to me.

I will appreciate your answer.

Comment: Why are you using CentOS 7?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm used to using CentOS 7 and my server provider only supports CentOS 6 and 7.

Comment: You definitely need a new provider then, and CentOS 8. It's crazy to keep using CentOS 7 for web sites these days.

Comment: @MichaelHampton They provide servers with huge resources and very cheap prices. I see no problem with CentOS 7.

Comment: You are already having the problem with CentOS 7!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"mod_php" (the main "php" package) is build with system httpd, so cannot be installed without it.

Using FPM (php-fpm) you can use any webserver.

I recommend you read [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips) which explain how to switch to FPM, and why it is better.

Notice:

- httpd 2.4 in CentOS 7 is maintained and have all security fixes, see [Backporting Security Fixes](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting/)
- More recent version is also available, with new features in the httpd24 Software Collections, maintain by the [SCLo SIG](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) from RHSCL.
- httpd 2.4 in CentOS 8 is also more recent (and use FPM by default)

Comment: httpd version on centos 7 when using my `yum` is 2.4.6-97 and php is 5.4.16-48. Do you think it's safe?

Comment: safe, yes. Updating to a new version is only mandatory if you need new features.